# Can you run a test within a test using the Intern?

Tags: javascript, functional-testing, intern

To demonstrate my issue, here is an oversimplification of what I'm trying to do:

I have two functional tests: `login` and `logout`. I have created a UI to allow for users (read: other devs) to select and run a given test(s) on a given browser(s).

It's pretty obvious that `logout` will fail if `login` wasn't run first. To solve this, I set a global variable `loggedIn` on the `login` test and added the following setup function to my `logout` test:

```
setup: function() {
    if (!globals.get('loggedIn')) {
        return require('./login')();
    }
},
```

This fails with the at the `require` statement with the following error message:

```
SUITE ERROR
Error: Attempt to require unloaded module tests/functional/login
```

How can I make it so that my setup function runs the `login` test, without copy-pasting the test into each of my test files?

---

#### Edit

The full test suite:

login.js

```
define([
    'intern!object',
    'intern/chai!assert',
    '../../var/globals'
], function(registerSuite, assert, globals) {
    registerSuite({
        name: 'logout',
        'logout': function() {
            return this.remote
                .get('www.example.com/login')
                .findById('status')
                    .getVisibleText()
                .then(function(text) {
                    var loggedIn = text === 'logged-in';
                    if (loggedIn) globals.set('loggedIn', true);
                    assert.equal(loggedIn, true);
                });
        }
    });
});
```

logout.js

```
define([
    'intern!object',
    'intern/chai!assert',
    'require',
    '../../var/globals'
], function(registerSuite, assert, require, globals) {
    registerSuite({
        name: 'logout',
        setup: function() {
            if (!globals.get('loggedIn')) {
                return require('./login')();
            }
        },
        'logout': function() {
            return this.remote
                .get('www.example.com/logout')
                .findById('status')
                    .getVisibleText()
                .then(function(text) {
                    assert.equal(text, 'logged-out');
                });
        }
    });
});
```

all.js

```
define([
    './login.js',
    './logout.js'
    // other tests that also depend on login.js
], function() {});
```

I want running the `logout` test to run `login`, and running the `all` test to run the `login` test *once*, regardless of how many other tests depend on `login`.

Comment: Please provide code for the entire module including the `define` wrapper. You’re probably using the 2-argument `define` and not including the `./login` module in your dependency list, but there is no way to verify this with the information you’ve provided.

Comment: @CSnover that is indeed what I am doing. I've edited my question to show the full module. I was under the assumption that adding the `./login` module to my dependency list would run it every time, regardless of whether or not it was already run?

Comment: Nevermind; it appears as though I can just stick the `./login` module within the dependency array of `define`, just like you said. I don't even need to use `require` or the setup function.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: The issue is caused by `require` being synchronous. Loading the module using the dependency array used in `define` will only run the tests once though. This means you can just add *any* test as a dependency, without changing any test groups (such as my `all` test).

This would change my modules to the following:

login.js

```
define([
    'intern!object',
    'intern/chai!assert',
    // globals var removed
], function(registerSuite, assert) {
    registerSuite({
        name: 'logout',
        'logout': function() {
            return this.remote
                .get('www.example.com/login')
                .findById('status')
                    .getVisibleText()
                .then(function(text) {
                    assert.equal(text, 'logged-in');
                });
        }
    });
});
```

logout.js

```
define([
    'intern!object',
    'intern/chai!assert',
    // require removed
    // globals var removed
    './login' // login module added
], function(registerSuite, assert) {
    registerSuite({
        name: 'logout',
        // setup method removed
        'logout': function() {
            return this.remote
                .get('www.example.com/logout')
                .findById('status')
                    .getVisibleText()
                .then(function(text) {
                    assert.equal(text, 'logged-out');
                });
        }
    });
});
```

all.js (remains the same)

```
define([
    './login.js',
    './logout.js'
    // other tests that also depend on login.js
], function() {});
```

Comment: You can use `require` to pull in tests, but not in the way you were trying to do it. AMD `require` is asynchronous, so to use it in a setup function to load a previously unloaded module, you'd need to wrap the require in a Promise that resolved after the `require` had finished loading the module.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Updated my answer to reflect that.